# C programming passing a char array into a function

Tags: c

I am using a function to parse through userID, and paswd and some error checking. The function is called from my main()... However when executed only the first 4 characters of my UserID and Pswd are successfully extracted. I am new to C-programming and coming from C# I am not sure where I am going wrong. This should be fairly easy, can someone point me in the right direction?

```
static void func1(int argc, char *argv[], char *UserID[30], char *Psw[30])
{
   strncpy(UserID, argv[1], sizeof(UserID));  
   strncpy(Psw, argv[2], sizeof(Psw));  
} 

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   char UserID[30];                          
   char Psw[30]; 
   func1(argc, argv, UserID, Psw);
}
```

Also, just to point out, if I don't use the external function, and have all the code in my main func then it works.

**EDIT:-**

Figured out the issue:-

```
static void func1(int argc, char *argv[], char *UserID, char *Psw)
{
   strncpy(UserID, argv[1], UserIDMaxSize);  
   strncpy(Psw, argv[2], PswMaxSize);   
} 

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   char UserID[UserIDMaxSize + 1];  /* max val defined in a header file */                        
   char Psw[PswMaxSize + 1];  /* max val defined in a header file */
   func1(argc, argv, UserID, Psw);
}
```

**sizeof** doesnt work quite as I expected it to.. it was reading the size of my pointer which is always 4 chars by default.

Comment: Did the compiler give you any warnings, what were they, and why did you ignore them?

Comment: 'function': 'char *' differs in levels of indirection from 'char **'

Comment: 'strncpy': different types for formal and actual parameter 1

Comment: `UserID` in `main` is `char[30]`, but you're passing it to an argument of type `char *[30]`. Notice the difference?

Comment: so what do you suggest?

Comment: Just take out the * before UserId and Psw.

Comment: tried it, and same result

Comment: nope. figured out the issue.

Comment: Please remove your solution from the *question*. Answers go in an **Answer** box on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I solved it simultaneously as chux.... I had a subtle difference in the answer as well. why would I remove that?

Comment: Do yourself a favor and don't even get into the habit of using functions like `strcpy()` or `strncpy()`. While the later is often labeled as "safe", its use still has two major pitfalls: 1. it requires an upper limit on the length of the string, and 2. it may trigger buffer overruns due to missing termination. Use allocating functions like `getline()`, `strdup()`, and `asprintf()` instead.

Comment: Philo, The reason to follow [@Rad Lexus](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2564301/rad-lexus) comment is to allow you to receive feedback on your answer separate from feedback on your question.  That is the SO model.   Self answering questions are promoted on SO, but answers belong in the answer section, and questions belong in the question, not a mixture.  Note: there are weaknesses to your solution.

Comment: @Philo He's saying you should add an answer to your question (as if it were someone else's) instead of editing the question ;)

Comment: Actaully chux, I am not showing my error checking statements in the code. so I don't think there are weaknesses per say.

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings. (for `gcc`, at a minimum, use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu99` )

Comment: the `strncpy()` function will not NUL terminate the destination buffer unless the source string is shorter than the length parameter.  Therefore, in the posted code, should follow each call to `strncpy()` with `destination[lengthofbuffer-1] = '\0';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the array size to the function

```
static void func1(int argc, char *argv[], char *UserID, size_t UserIDSize, 
    char *Psw, size_t PswSize)
{
   if (argc> 1) strncpy(UserID, argv[1], UserIDSize);  
   if (argc> 2) strncpy(Psw, argv[2], PswSize);  
} 

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   char UserID[30] = {0};     
   char Psw[30] = {0};
   func1(argc, argv, UserID, sizeof UserID, Psw, sizeof Psw);
}
```

To insure the destination arrays are null character terminated, suggest `strncat()` --> "A terminating null character is always appended to the result."  `strncpy()` has too many problems, it does not always result in an array with a null character.

```
static void func1(int argc, char *argv[], char *UserID, size_t UserIDSize, 
    char *Psw, size_t PswSize) {
   UserId[0] = '\0';
   // if (argc> 1) strncat(UserID, argv[1], UserIDSize);  
   if (argc> 1) strncat(UserID, argv[1], UserIDSize - 1);  
   Psw[0] = '\0';
   // if (argc> 2) strncat(Psw, argv[2], PswSize);  
   if (argc> 2) strncat(Psw, argv[2], PswSize - 1);  
}
```

[Edit]

Corrected code - off by 1

Answer (score 3):

I guess your pointer has a size of 4 Byte. therefore you only read 4 chars.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR

The `sizeof` isn't doing what you're expecting. Try using `strlen` instead.

---

You're only getting 4 characters copied because `sizeof(char*[N])` for any *N* is just going to be the size of a pointer. On your platform, a pointer must be 4 bytes (32 bits).

I think you actually mean to pass the base-address of the array into the function, but in that case your types aren't quite right. Your compiler should be warning you about this. You should remove the `*` from your last 2 argument types:

```
static void func1(int argc, char *argv[], char UserID[30], char Psw[30])
```

That should get rid of the warning, and it should actually make `sizeof` behave correctly as well (since `sizeof(char[30])` is 30). However, it's very easy to make mistakes with `sizeof` since the behavior with a `char*` and `char[]` are different... I'd prefer using `strlen` (or `strnlen` if you want to avoid possible buffer overflows) here instead, which will simply tell you how many non-null characters you have.

Using `strnlen` rather than `sizeof` would also help to tip you off that your parameter types are wrong, since it will complain that you're trying to pass a `char**` to a function that expects a `char*`.

Comment: If I use strlen as it is in the code, then I only get the numbers in my userID and Pswd, the rest of the characters are null-terminated....Also, just to point out, if I don't use the external function, and have all the code in my main func then it works.

Comment: As Scott Hunter pointed out in his comment, you should be getting some compiler warnings with this code because you have a type mismatch... If you fix those warnings then it'd probably work.

Answer (score -1):

Solution

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void func1(int argc, char *argv[], char *UserID, char *Psw)
{
   strncpy(UserID, argv[1], strlen(argv[1]));
   strncpy(Psw, argv[2], strlen(argv[2]));
printf("DATA: %s \n",UserID);
printf("DATA1: %s \n",Psw);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   char UserID[30];
   char Psw[30];
        printf("argv1 %ld \n",strlen(argv[1]));
        printf("argv2 %ld \n",strlen(argv[2]));
   func1(argc, argv, UserID, Psw);
}
```

Comment: still the same problem, only the first 4 characters

Comment: consistent indenting would make this code much more readable by us humans.